# 4g usb modem not working after modeswith

Tags: ubuntu-touch, modem, huawei, broadband, 4g

Recently I was trying to make my 4g mobile boroadband (Huawei e3372) work on my ubuntu 12.04,so I followed the instructions in this link http://bytefish.de/blog/huawei_e352s5/, and execute these commandes with my own info for -v and -P in first and second command.

```
usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'
```

and

```
echo "12d1 1506" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

but after that, is it no more connecting to the internet even on windows on which it worked normally,and it has somthing to do with modeswitch,
Is there any way I can undo this commands or make it work by some other means (maybe restoring to defaults settings).please help.
Thanks in advance.